# Staging without committing (git)

Tags: git

We know that, in git, when we stage a file with

```
git add readme.txt
```

the "readme.txt" file is not committed, and it remains so until we use

```
git commit readme.txt -m "..."
```

But I cannot imagine that such a situation is useful. In what situation  do we ever need to stage a file without committing it?

Comment: so you can build up your commit iteratively?

Comment: basically staging is a place where you build your commit before actually committing it. You can add several files, parts of files, select lines, review your changes...

Comment: Once you have specifically staged `readme.txt` you generally *do not* want to mention it, nor any other files, on the `git commit` command.  The reason is that if you *do* list some files when running `git commit`, it defaults to `git commit --only`, i.e., ignores the files you have already staged.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want to ask here is "what good is staging" or "why bother with an index".  It's true that the index/staging-area is not necessary: Mercurial gets away without having one, for instance.  However, the index provides for a lot of Stupid Git Tricks, while also containing pitfalls (including `--only` vs `--include` and a long answer I made recently on that), so it would definitely be a change to *not* have it.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/36242914/1256452

Comment: @torek  Your comment makes a lot of sense to me. Thanks so much.

Comment: I think about 70% of my commits consist of multiple files. Also, often I don't commit an entire file, but only parts (using `--patch`). My workflow is to look through all my changes and add those parts I want to commit first. Building up a commit like this makes my commit history way clearer than committing file by file. Note that after you `git add` you don't need to name the file in `git commit`.

Answer (score 3):

It is useful if you want to commit it *later*.

You could for example, stage it today, and continue to work on the project tomorrow (you think the modified file is okay, but still have to fix others and add unit tests). Having staged the file gives you a "savepoint" of sorts. You can then do things like diff against the staged version.

A common workflow is to immediately stage new files (even though they are still empty), so that they show up as "modified" instead of "untracked" and you don't later forget to include them in the commit. Many IDE do that automatically when you create new source code files.

> git commit readme.txt -m "..."

Actually, you would probably not be saying "commit readme.txt". You can commit without listing any files, and it will commit everything that was staged before.

Comment: Thanks. But you can also do all things at the git-commit level. Using your example, we can commit today, continue to work on the working directory, compare the diff between the committed snapshot with the working directory, and at last you merge several commits into one.

Comment: Sure. There is more than one way to do this. Some people have a rule that commits should be "complete". And git allows you to have "private branches" to be very flexible. There is also the "stash" mechanism.

Comment: People would probably disagree on this: It seems that, to some extend, "git add" is redundant. The benefits of having "git add" seems marginal compared with the extra complexity that it introduces for both its learners and users.

Comment: If you are going to commit only files as they exist in the working copy, then you could get by without `git add`, I guess. But I like to review the changes one by one (adding them), and that process sometimes takes time. Also, sometimes I commit only parts of a file (which I think would be difficult without `git add`).